# OpenAPI escapes JSON response in Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, openapi-generator

I recently tried to generate OpenAPI documentation for my Sprint Boot application. I added the following lines to my `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.30</version>
</dependency>
```

But when I hit the swagger-ui URL on my localhost I get this page
[image]

I checked the JSON at `/v3/api-docs` and I get a response that starts:

```
"{\"openapi\":\"3.0.1\",\"info\":{\"title\":\"OpenAPI definition\",\"version\":\"v0\"},\"servers\":[{\"url\":\"https://localhost:8900/tds\",
```

I can see that the `openapi` field is being specified, but it looks like the entire response is stringified instead of just being JSON. Since there doesn't seem to be any configuration for OpenAPI, I assume it's getting that from something in my Spring Boot configuration, but I have no idea where.

Comment: what you get when you hit http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html? are you able to open the swagger-ui.html

Comment: @dassum The screenshot is of swagger-ui.html on my localhost

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @TobiasLott No, I haven’t had much time to investigate further. If you find a solution please add an answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem. In my case, I have overridden `configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters)` in the class extending `WebMvcConfigurer`. Springdoc uses the converters that are configured there.

First I had some custom converter added to the converters first, and then the `StringHttpMessageConverter`. The `canWrite(Class<?> clazz, MediaType mediaType)` method of both converters returned `true` for `clazz` = `String.class` and `mediaType` = `application/json`. Thus the first one was used, which escaped the JSON as string.

When I changed it so that the `StringHttpMessageConverter` is added first, that one is used instead, and serializes the JSON object without escaping.

Comment: What helped me was using `extendMessageConverters` instead of `configureMessageConverters` in the `WebMvcConfigurer`.

Recommendation found here: https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/216#issuecomment-584409448

Answer (score 3):

This is a small workaround, just point to yaml version:
springdoc.swagger-ui.url=/v3/api-docs.yaml

gson is configured as the default JSON parser

Comment: thanks a lot, this workaround is really helped me. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in Spring Boot 2.5.3:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/releases/tag/v2.5.3

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/27361